# How to use OpenCV with Qt5

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5

I'm migrating my code from Qt4 to Qt5 that uses OpenCV to take shots from the Webcam and display it on QLabel, on Qt4 everything works fine, but in Qt5 i have a trouble. The libstdc++-6.dll that is required both from Qt and OpenCV are different (the used by OpenCV has 957 KB(i got it by download of MinGW on the SourceForge page), and the required by Qt5 that came with the Qt5 installer has 874 KB) and when i try to use one i got this error: "The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll" and when i try to use another dll i got this error: "The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_sj0 could not be located in the dynamic link library libstdc++-6.dll". What i can do to solve this issue and use OpenCV with Qt5?

Comment: I think compiling opencv from source would be quite easy, much easier than compiling qt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution: Use a vc11 precompiled libraries (which does not require the libstdc++-6.dll and thus prevents conflicts with libstdc++-6.dll required by Qt5) instead of use a MinGW precompiled libraries of OpenCV.